# Скрипт для понижения безопасности

Tags: vba, vbscript

**Задание таково:** Написать скрипт (программу на VBScript, языке из семейства языков VB), понижающий уровень безопасности заданного приложения MSO (Word, Excel, Access) и открывающий заданный документ MSO в этом приложении.

Честно говоря - не до конца понимаю, как это можно реализовать понижение безопасности в access, а так же - как создать и открыть документы с пониженной безопасностью.

Ниже представлен то, что у меня сейчас есть:

```
Sub LowSecurityExcel()
    On Error Resume Next
    Key$ = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\Security\FileBlock\"
    arr = Array("XL2Macros", "XL2Worksheets", "XL3Macros", "XL3Worksheets", _
        "XL4Macros", "XL4Workbooks", "XL4Worksheets")
    For Each Item In arr
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite Key$ & Item, 0, "REG_DWORD"
    Next
End Sub

Sub LowSecurityWord()
    On Error Resume Next
    Key$ = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Word\Security\FileBlock\"
    arr = Array("XL2Macros", "XL2Worksheets", "XL3Macros", "XL3Worksheets", _
        "XL4Macros", "XL4Workbooks", "XL4Worksheets")
    For Each Item In arr
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite Key$ & Item, 0, "REG_DWORD"
    Next
End Sub

Sub LowSecutrityAccess()
    On Error Resume Next
    Key$ = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Access\Security\FileBlock\"
    arr = Array("XL2Macros", "XL2Worksheets", "XL3Macros", "XL3Worksheets", _
        "XL4Macros", "XL4Workbooks", "XL4Worksheets")
    For Each Item In arr
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite Key$ & Item, 0, "REG_DWORD"
    Next
End Sub

Sub Enable_AccessVBA()
    On Error Resume Next
    Key$ = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & _
        "\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite Key$, 1, "REG_DWORD"
End Sub
```

У этих начертаний есть одно "но" - сделано на VBA, и на каких то устройствах работает, а на каких то - нет.

Comment: Сперва общие замечания по коду.
1. Зачем прописывать настройки экселя в ветках ворда и акцесса - совсем не понятно.
2. `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` в цикле - очень плохая идея. Определите его через переменную вначале процедуры и используйте уже ее. например так: `Dim wsshell as Object`, `Set wsshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` и уже в цикле вызывайте `wsshell.RegWrite ...`

Comment: Теперь по самой задаче. Понижение уровня безопасности через код - очень... ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея! На подобный код многие антивирусы могут возбудиться и заблокировать его выполнение. По поводу VBA и того, что где-то не работает. VBS и VBA в большинстве своем совместимы по синтаксису. Попробуйте сохранить код в файл `*.vbs` и выполнить